# In Laravel what's the difference between public and storage path?

Tags: php, laravel

I am brand new to Laravel and php and I noticed that there are two different folders that have public on them. One is `public/storage` and the other is `storage/app/public` , what is the difference between the both of them? Where should I be putting my files that I want to use like images and my CSS styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `public/storage` is just a symlink of `storage/app/public` so both are the same,

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel provides excellent filesystems abstraction and it is very simple to use.

The **public disk** is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

When using the **local driver**, all file operations are relative to the root directory defined in your filesystems configuration file. By default, this value is set to the storage/app directory.

Here is link to documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem